# Error while trying to run project: Unable to start program 'Mono'. Operation not supported. Unknown error: 0x80004005

Tags: xamarin, mono, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms, visual-studio-2017

I get this [error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jdyBD.png) just as I am deploying the .droid project in the solution:

Error while trying to run project: Unable to start program 'Mono'. Operation not supported. Unknown error: 0x80004005.

I'm running Visual Studio 2017 and deploying to a Samsung Galaxy Tab S2. It used to work fine before I upgraded from Visual Studio 2015.

The app installs on the device but does not run in debug when deploying.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: I found a way around this error by changing the order of the startup projects.

In my case, I needed to start the .droid project **before** a WPF project I was also trying to run.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not able to comment so I'll post and answer.

Try to unninstall your app from your device.

1. Remove it on the settings section of your phone;
2. Go to internal extorage/android/data and remvove all folders related to your app (your app name).

Then try to run your application again from VS.